# Error when sending data over network?

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets, networking, network-programming

I've made a small program that allows a user to remotely control their home computer from any computer that obviously has a internet connection, but i keep getting this error whenever i try to send a test command to my laptop...

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: buffer
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>
> at svchost.Form1.accept_Client() in C:\Users\Samuel\documents\visual studio\2012\Projects\svchost\svchost\Form1.vb:line 40

Here's my code...

```
Imports STE

Public Class Form1 'PS, client_info is a rich text box...

Private serverListener As New Net.Sockets.TcpListener(9653) 'list for incoming connections
Private serverSender As New Net.Sockets.TcpClient 'send data back to client
Private byteFromClient() As Byte 'Allows max of 1024 characters from client.
Private byteFromServer() As Byte 'Allows max of 1024 characters from server.
Private stringFromServer As String = ""
Private stringFromClient As String = ""
Private streamFromServer As Net.Sockets.NetworkStream
Private streamFromClient As Net.Sockets.NetworkStream
Private pendingClient As New Net.Sockets.TcpClient 'client to handle
Private secure As New STE.Encryption 'encrypt data

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Recive.CancelAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Recive.RunWorkerAsync() 'Start listening thread
End Sub

Private Sub Recive_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles Recive.DoWork
    serverListener.Start() 'start listening to incoming information from clients
    Do While True
        If serverListener.Pending = True Then
            Call accept_Client()
        End If
        If Recive.CancellationPending = True Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub accept_Client()
    Try
        pendingClient = serverListener.AcceptTcpClient
        pendingClient.GetStream.Read(byteFromClient, 0, pendingClient.ReceiveBufferSize) 'Error here...
        stringFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteFromClient)
        client_info.Text = stringFromClient & vbNewLine
    Catch ex As Exception
        client_info.Text = ex.ToString
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Transmit_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles Transmit.DoWork
    Try
        Do While serverSender.Connected = False
            serverSender.Connect("127.0.0.1", 9653) 'connect to local pc (temp)...
        Loop
        byteFromServer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(commandTB.Text)
        streamFromServer.Write(byteFromServer, 0, byteFromServer.Length) 'write data to stream
        streamFromServer.Flush() 'send data
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString & vbNewLine & ex.InnerException.Data.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub send_command_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles send_command.Click
    Transmit.RunWorkerAsync() 'start thread to transmit data to client
End Sub
End Class
```

Network programming is currently a weak area for me, so i'm not even sure if my code has the correct logic. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim byteFromClient(1024) As Byte
```

Comment: Thanks, that's got rid of the error, but now nothing happens, i don't receive the incoming data.

Comment: Data is in your array but it is not full of data. To find out how much data is written to it check return value of your `Read` function. You should read data within a loop until you read all data. 1K (1024) maybe not enough for your purpose. Be careful if you are reading by the same buffer, set `offset` so your previous read data won't overwritten.

Comment: Right ok,  would i use something like this? Dim i As Integer = 0
            Do While i < pendingClient.ReceiveBufferSize
                pendingClient.GetStream.Read(byteFromClient, i, 1024)
                i = i + 1
            Loop

Comment: @Sam: Good approach is using a fixed buffer and write it contents somewhere else i.e. file, when filled (check how much data is in it as I said before). For your while condition use `while Reader.Read` (I'm not sure of syntax in VB), this will check if end of stream is reached.